# how to toggle between two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all, there is an unfinished live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/johndoe1992/xcqm8enj/

So, I have two divs - `.one` and `.two`

By default, inside `.one` there is another div - `.container`

Inside `.container` there are two images - `.first` and `.second`

`.container` is dynamically toggling between `.one` and `.two`

Toggling between `.one` and `.two` it's not the problem, the real problem is:

1) If `.container`'s parent() is `.one`:
when I hover on `.one` it must display image `.first` (fade in/fade out preferable). Image `.second` still "display: none"

2) If `.container`'s parent() is `.two`:
when I hover on `.two` it must display image `.second` (fade in/out too). Image `.first` - "display: none"

The visible part of this app looks like that example https://jsfiddle.net/johndoe1992/o8grgfaL/ but inside there are so many differences, as you can see

Help me, please

Comment: `but inside there are so many differences, as you can see`. I can't see what you mean, can you explain please?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "`.container is dynamically toggling between .one and .two`"? is `container` class added to one of those or is it a div inserted into them?

Comment: @Aziz - `.container` class may be the children element only to one of those classes

Comment: @A1rPun - I have two divs - `.one` and `.two`, inside only one of them there is another div `.container` that contains two images. If `.container` is a children to `.one`, it must display first image in the div `.one`. If `.container` is a children to `.two`, it must display second image in the div `.two`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead go for context with `this`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.one, .two').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).find('img').stop().fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).find('img').stop().fadeOut();
    }
  });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8grgfaL/1/)